# What type is the content when you are sending files from browser?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api

I'm posting a `FormData` with my front-end to upload a file (uploadReq is a HttpRequest)

```
 this.http.request(uploadReq).subscribe(event => {
      if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress)
        this.progress = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total!);
      else if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response && event.body !== null)
        this.message = event.body.toString();
    });
```

This then goes into a method in webapi:

```
   [HttpPost]
   [Route("api/uploadFiles")]
   public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadFile()
```

Where I have a check like so:

```
 if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
```

Now everything is working fine if it's just those 2 communicating. However I need to pass this request through a gateway service, and I don't know what type should I accept and output:

```
 [OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "uploadFiles")]
 Task<bool> uploadFiles(//what type should myFile be? Stream? StreamContent? byte[]? Something other?// myFile);
```

I will then need to `PostAsync` the file in this method:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ApiUrl);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("multipart/form-data"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", someauth)));

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("uploadFiles", //what should I pass here?//);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```

**The problem:**

My current attempts to make this work result in either a `400 bad request` or faile the `if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())` check with `406` error code.

**The questions:**

1. What type should `myFile` be in the OperationContract declaration?
2. What should I pass as a parameter to the `PostAsync` method?

EDIT: Through some trial and error (and a lot of googling) I came up with this:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{                           
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(SalesQuotationApiUrl);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();                           
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("multipart/form-data"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", someAuth)));
    MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    var streamContent = new StreamContent(myFile);
    var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(streamContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result);
    fileContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data");
    form.Add(fileContent, "myFile", "index.html");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("uploadFiles", form);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```

This actually sends the file to the web api and it's saved. **However**, this introduced 2 new problems for me:

1. How do I know the file name at this stage? `form.Add(fileContent, "quoteFiles", "index.html");` <- this is hardcoded, I would like to have the original file name
2. Some junk gets appended to the file - for example, when sending an html file the start of it looks like so:

> ------WebKitFormBoundaryAOjBy1u08n59PPW0 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="index.html"; filename="index.html" Content-Type:
>   text/html

How to I remove this clutter?

Comment: Some tips 1FTP (uses http) has two modes a) Text b) Binary When using Binary nothing get changed. Text mode the return character gets modified if different from local and remote machine.For example if you go from windows to unix windows uses CR-LF while unix uses CR so the character get changed. 2) HTTP has special characters to you cannot send binary. Binary data has to be converted to a 64 bit string. 3) If you are using Mime the Mine attachment(s) can be binary and do not need the 64 bit string.The error message 406 indicates the http headers in the request are not consistent with the body.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a method that worked for me (sent the file, properly handled headers and original file names). Maybe someone can find this usefull:

```
 var incomingContentType = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.ContentType;
 var streamContent = new StreamContent(myFile);
 var incomingContentBody = streamContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
 var client = new RestClient("yourApiRouteHere");
 var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

 request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
 request.AddHeader("Authorization", "yourAuthHere");
 request.AddHeader("content-type", incomingContentType);
 request.AddParameter(incomingContentType, incomingContentBody, ParameterType.RequestBody);

 IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
 if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
     return true;
```